Solana Airdrop Devnet issue
I am brand new and am having issues.  I have created a file system wallet via CLI, my config is set to devnet and the wallet shows up, my balance is 0.  I have requested an airdrop of 1 with the command: solana airdrop 1 but I get Error: airdrop request failed. This can happen when the rate limit is reached.
I looked up info and saw that i might need to use solana airdrop 1 -k AihNKmpVQdFyhFfccvm1d2VzJ5bjvQAiKrUHLxYkb76v --url devnet  which includes my public key  that returned
Error: Dynamic program error: missing signature for supplied pubkey: AihNKmpVQdFyhFfccvm1d2VzJ5bjvQAiKrUHLxYkb76v
so I used the local filepath method solana airdrop 1 -k /Users/rakes/.config/solana/krnftest.json --url devnet
and I get the same error as before Error: airdrop request failed. This can happen when the rate limit is reached.
Can someone please explain what I might be doing wrong?  why no airdrop?  Why is the public key missing signature?

The airdrop request failed. This can happen when the rate limit is reached error is due to rate limits.
You'll need to wait till your rate limits are lifted, usually a day or try out another faucet e.g https://faucet.solana.com/
Find more on this list https://solana.com/es/developers/guides/getstarted/solana-token-airdrop-and-faucets
